# Allowing access to multiple Roles Using User.IsInRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
//Link goes here.
}
```

That all works fine and dandy but what do I do when I would like to allow multiply roles such as:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin, SuperUser")) {
//Link goes here.
}
```

Comment: `if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperUser"))`

Comment: @BradleyUffner you're right :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the conditional-OR operator (||). 
See Microsoft documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperUser") {
//Link goes here.
}
```

Comment: @Chantry If this was the solution, please mark as answer.